# Can't connect to Azure SQL server using docker

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, docker, azure-sql-database

I am new to docker and I can't seem to figure this one out...

I have a spring boot application connected to an azure sql database which is running fine in my IDE, but when running my app in a docker container I am getting the following error:

> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: ".database.windows.net. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

Dockerfile:

```
COPY pom.xml /build/

COPY src /build/src/

WORKDIR /build/

RUN mvn package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ADD target/spring-boot-docker.jar /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-boot-docker.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=8081

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://<hidden>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<hidden>;user=<hidden>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
spring.datasource.username=<hidden>
spring.datasource.password=<passhidden>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be a network connectivity issue.

Chances are high that you can't get out from a dynamic internal port to port 1433 on the server, from within the docker container.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Start by using tracert from within the docker container to make sure you have a route to the IP address of the server.